# Remove devise email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I use devise and devise-token-auth. I have User model with following content

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  validates_uniqueness_of :login
  validates_presence_of :full_name

  protected
  def email_required?
    puts "email_required called"
    false
  end
end
```

but devise email validation is still working

```
2.3.0 :003 > user = User.new(login: "hello", password: "11111111", password_confirmation: "11111111", full_name: "hello world")
 => #<User id: nil, provider: "email", uid: "", email: nil, full_name: "hello world", login: "hello", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.0 :004 > user.valid?
email_required? called   #<===== my method is called!
   (3.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."email" IS NULL  [["provider", "email"]]
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["login", "hello"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => false 
2.3.0 :005 > user.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000028e2338 @messages={:email=>[...]}, @details={:email=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

Why this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please try this. Move `email_required?` method into `user.rb`

Comment: `email_required?` already in `user.rb`

Comment: remove `protected` from `user.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Your validations do not override the Devise validations, they just extend them. If you really want to remove the Devise validations, you can remove the :validatable module. But you will lose all the nifty validations (e.g. on the password) as well.

Or maybe try to do this first: (I didn't test this)
`:authentication_keys => {email: false, login: true}`

Comment: Thank you, but it too did not help. I decided to remove validatable

Comment: By the way. In the console: the`puts` statement prevents the execution of the rest of the code. You better type `byebug` after `false` and see in console what the output value is.

Comment: it works for me https://github.com/motoroller95/iMed/blob/master/app/models/user.rb#L7

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove email validation. Edit User model to

```
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable,
   :trackable, :validatable, authentication_keys: [:password]
```

If you comletely want to remove validations. Remove ***validatable*** from User model.

Comment: this skips password comparison as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed to username field. First I changed `/config/initializers/devise.rb` --> `config.authentication_keys = [:username]`

And, as I use a legacy database, I have to change the primary key to username too and change the `auth` method

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  login = conditions.delete(:username)
  where(["APP_NAME = '#{$app_name.downcase}' AND USERNAME = :value", { :value => login }]).first
end
```