# Allow multiple users with same email with Devise Token Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I'd like to allow multiple users with the same email to be created, using [devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth).

Rather than this error being thrown.

```
@details={:email=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>"testttt@gmail.com"}]}>
```

I expected that removing `devise :validatable` from `user.r`b would have worked, but it did not.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
end
```

I found this a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725552/remove-devise-email-validation) from years ago, but the suggestions did not work.

I'm wondering if this is specifically a devise-token-auth issue, rather than devise.

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 0):

I could only find a hacky way to achieve this so far, and wanted to share.

Given there doesn't appear to be a simple way to do this.

I had to set the `provider` method from `DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::ResourceFinder` to `nil`. The default is hardcoded `"email"`.

```
    def provider
      nil
    end
```

So when `build_resource` is called in the `registrations_controller.rb`, it won't auto set `provider="email"`.

Without `provider="email"`, the "Email already taken" error no longer thrown.

```
    def build_resource
      @resource            = resource_class.new(sign_up_params)
      @resource.provider   = provider

      # honor devise configuration for case_insensitive_keys
      if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(:email)
        @resource.email = sign_up_params[:email].try(:downcase)
      else
        @resource.email = sign_up_params[:email]
      end
    end
```

But by changing the logic above, `uid` is no longer updated with the value of the user's email. So I added a callback on `User.rb` to compensate.

```
  after_initialize do
    self.uid = self.email
  end
```

This works, but I'd love a simpler way to achieve this.